# Grouping elements into two columns and aligning them to the top (with Flexbox)

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

HTML code (the structure should not be modified):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">1</div>
    <div class="right">2</div>
    <div class="right">3</div>
    <div class="right">4</div>
    <div class="left">5</div>
    <div class="left">6</div>
    <div class="right">7</div>
<div>
```

Expected result (two columns, no gaps):

```
+-----------+-------+
|     1     |   2   |
|           |-------|
|-----------|   3   |
|     5     |       |
|           |-------|
|-----------|   4   |
|     6     |-------|
|-----------|   7   |
|           |       |
+-----------+-------+
```

Children elements can have any amount of the content (in most cases their height will never be equal).

`.left` elements have a width of 70%, `.right` – 30%.

HTML code should be as is, because the structural order of elements is a requirement on narrow screens (it will shrink to a single-column layout), and I want to have two columns on wider screens as shown in the scheme.

Using `float` produces unwanted gaps on the right side. Is **Flexbox** capable of solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to achieve this layout without having gaps between containers.

The only way I could make this work was with javascript (I used masonry)

The Html:

```
<div class="container js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
<div class="item left">1 </div>
<div class="item right">2 </div>
<div class="item right">3</div> 
<div class="item right">4</div>
<div class="item left">5</div>
<div class="item left">6</div>
<div class="item right">7</div>
<div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.left {width:70%;background-color:#ccc;}
.right {width:30%;background-color:#d00;float:right;}
.stamp {position:relative !important; clear:right;}
```

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/razvan/pen/Iydwg

Answer (score 0):

Let's give it a **GO**:

```
SAME HTML + some css classes
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item left">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item right">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item right">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item right">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item left">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item left">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item right">7</div>
<div>

reset basic
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

THE CSS
    *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-item{
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 1;
}

.left{
  width: 70%;
  order: 1;
}

.right{
  width: 30%;
  order: 3;
}

.break{
  order: 2;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

JQUERY
// Adds element after the last LEFT
$('.left').last().after('<div class="break"></div>');
```

Well, that is it here is a  [CodePen](http://codepen.io/T04435/pen/XpBzZG) for It.

Thanks.